# Which native Windows library deals with files, file sizes, created dates? (for use with JNI)

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

I need to write a JNI wrapper for windows file system calls. I want to be able to get the size and created date of files on a windows system using the appropriate native library. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetFileAttributesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946(VS.85).aspx) to get the creation time from the filename. or [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952(VS.85).aspx)  if you already have the file open.

The library is kernel32.dll

Answer (score 1):

should be able to find what you need [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks objects, I don't see where I can get the created date in that list - do you know where that function is? or how I do it? thanks

Comment: the call is documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946(VS.85).aspx

And the structure used here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365739(VS.85).aspx